# could not open camera for the first time in moto devices and samsung s6

Tags: java, android, wowza

On starting streaming using Wowza Streaming Cloud through goCoder SDK the, camera doesn't open in Moto g and Samsung s6 at that time but when I switch the camera then both camera(back and front) work properly. In other words camera doesn't open for first time(a black screen is shown).

These are the attributes I am using in my xml file.

```
<com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.api.devices.WOWZCameraView
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
wowza:defaultCamera="back"
wowza:frameSizePreset="frameSize1280x720"
wowza:scaleMode="fill" />
```

using `startPreview()` method of `WOWZCameraView` instance to start the camera in `onResume` method of Activity and as far as Sampleapp of wowza is concerned, I am able to start the camera without any issues.

Comment: Do you handle the permissions correctly for first time?

Comment: yes  i am handling it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Wowza has released a new SDK version and this release contains a fix for the camera preview aspect ratio and START event issues you reported. Download the new release and see if your problem is resolved.